# How do you sync many writable MongoDB databases?

Tags: mongodb

What I mean by witable is that you can CRUD on each database, and **it automatically syncs with the other so that all of them are synced all the time** (as much as possible).

I want to start a project for a company with some tricks.
The company is present in many locations (at least 5) and wants the app to run locally (with local database), but when there's a change(Create Update or Delete), the change is propagated to the other databases.

The goal is to have them all synced at every moment, but with the possibility that if internet connection is lost on one site, they continue to use the app properly since they are actually connected to the local database. That's why they don't one a totally online database.

They use MongoDB.

I saw the replica sets technology, but since it's with a unique master, it seems complicated.
Please can you share solutions to such a situation?

Comment: This is not a problem that can be simply answered here. Replica sets go in the right direction. But there is an entire area of research behind this. Look into the CAP theorem for example.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. You say Replica sets go in the right direction, then how could I use them?

Comment: Maybe read this one: https://www.instaclustr.com/blog/cassandra-vs-mongodb/